# Include unrelated patent on publication list

Tags: publications, faculty-application

I am a PhD candidate (Statistics) starting to apply to academic jobs. I have no publications related to my research - besides my in-process dissertation.
One of my applications requires a publication list.

I have a patent awarded 7 years ago when I worked in a completely different field.  Should I include it in the publications list? I do plan on adding my in-process dissertation just so that I dont turn in a blank page.

Comment: Yeah sure.  I would include any non-stats papers as well (e.g. if you have anything in the natural or social sciences, even non-mathematical).  I would do that even if you had a bunch of stats papers.

Comment: Why don't you have any papers?  Can't you carve up parts of the dissertation and publish them?  Can't you at least do some stats consulting support for experimentalists or social scientists (e.g. medical papers) and get some fourth author publications?

Comment: Finally, it would be nice to put down a bunch "submitted" papers on your list.  Doesn't need to be done yet.  But at least somethings in the chute.

Comment: All of these are good ideas, but can't happen in the next week.

Comment: How about some "in preparation for" papers?  Do the patent, the thesis and 3 (or so) "in prep" papers.  That would be 5 (or so) total.  You have to be serious about carving your thesis up this way, but presumably you are.  Than just make a separate file for each chapter.  Honestly, I think it's easier to publish first and then stitch the thesis.  But I am a scummy experimentalist.

Comment: It's not even as sleazy as it sounds.  At least it shows you are planning on getting some pubs out.  And the fact that they are chapters of your in progress thesis makes it really more tangible (since there is some work there).  Not just a dream with nothing at all done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should list it. Even if you had an otherwise rich CV it would still be proper to list it.

Your application needs to make your best case for acceptance and any IP contributions show evidence of quality research. People understand that patents are hard to obtain.

Your application otherwise will show mostly work in progress, which is fine, but work completed is also a good indicator. You might want to explain your change of fields if that is relevant also, or, at least be prepared to discuss it.